# Maintain Array Order Between TableViews?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I've got 2 tableViews that I'm trying to display separate arrays on from the same struct.  The second array/tableView is just a subset of the first; the user can select the first tableView's row and that object get's duplicated onto the second array/tableView.  I'd like the order to be the same, however, and I haven't found a way to do that with structs.

```
struct SomeTasks {
  var name: String
  var listOfPossibleThings: [List]
  var listOfActualThings: [List]
}

struct List {
  var name: String
  var items: [Item]
}

struct Item {
  var name: String
}
```

The user creates new List objects in the listOfPossibleThings array, and can move them to/from listOfActualThings.

TableViewOne uses someTasks.listOfPossibleThings to populate it's cells; for the structs that do get moved to tableViewTwo I'd like the order to remain the same.  What is the best practice to perform this order logic with structs?  Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me like you are saying you do not know what order the list should be in?

Comment: I'd like the objects that get duplicated into the second array to be in the same order as they were in the first array.

Comment: But what is the order in the first array? And if you pass the objects from the first view to the second, the order wouldn't change.

Comment: The order is based on when the user creates a new object, and gets updated if the user re-orders the cells in the tableView. I allow the user to tap on any cell in tableViewOne to add to the second array/tableViewTwo, so the order follows however they tap.  If the user creates someTasksOne and someTasksTwo (in that order), and they tap someTasksTwo and then someTasksOne, the secondTableView get's populates in that incorrect order.

Comment: Ah i see. You have to create a new array and keep appending the items as you click them. Append maintains the order of clicking. Be mindful of the logic for clicking on the same row multiple times, deletion, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Managing the order of two arrays is difficult and error prone, I think it might be better to have only one array stored and the other computed every time you needed it.

Something like this

```
struct someTasks {
    var name: String
    var listOfPossibleThings: [List]
    var listOfActualThings: [List] {listOfPossibleThings.filter {$0.isActualThing}}
}

struct List {
    var name: String
    var items: [Item]
    var isActualThing: Bool = false
}

struct Item {
    var name: String
}

var foo = someTasks(name: "foo", listOfPossibleThings: [
    List(name: "list0", items: [Item(name: "item0.0")]),
    List(name: "list1", items: [Item(name: "item0.0"), Item(name: "item0.1")])
])


foo.listOfPossibleThings  // list0, list1
foo.listOfPossibleThings[1].isActualThing = true
foo.listOfActualThings    // list1
foo.listOfPossibleThings[0].isActualThing = true
foo.listOfActualThings    // list0, list1
```